# PANDAS : Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data-frames :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["Bag room","Bag Scan", "Bag Screening Equipment"],'CC': ["AAA","BBB", "CCC"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["SIN_SATS LTD_DOC-Bag Scan :Aug","SIN_SATS LTD_DOC-Bag room :Aug","EDI_EDINBURGH AIRPORT LTD_DOC-Bag Screening Equipment :Sep"]})
```

I am using the below code to extract the substring in df1 from string in df2 and finally to return the content of CC column. It works great as in the example below:

```
pat = '|'.join(df1['Item'].values)
df2['Item_Description'] = df2['Item'].str.extract(f"({pat})")
df2['CC'] = df2['Item_Description'].map(df1.set_index('Item')['CC'])
```

[image]

However, when I add brackets to the item :Bag Screening (Equipment) and EDI_EDINBURGH AIRPORT LTD_DOC-Bag Screening (Equipment) :Sep and I use the same code to extract substring I receive the below error :
Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Is there any way to handle this issue or do I have to just remove brackets from the item before using the code?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["Bag room","Bag Scan", "Bag Screening (Equipment)"],'CC': ["AAA","BBB", "CCC"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["SIN_SATS LTD_DOC-Bag Scan :Aug","SIN_SATS LTD_DOC-Bag room :Aug","EDI_EDINBURGH AIRPORT LTD_DOC-Bag Screening (Equipment) :Sep"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the special characters. For this [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) is handy:

```
import re
pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['Item'].values))

df2['Item_Description'] = df2['Item'].str.extract(f"({pat})")
df2['CC'] = df2['Item_Description'].map(df1.set_index('Item')['CC'])
```

details of the pattern without or with escape:

```
'|'.join(df1['Item'].values)
# 'Bag room|Bag Scan|Bag Screening (Equipment)'

'|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['Item'].values))
# 'Bag\\ room|Bag\\ Scan|Bag\\ Screening\\ \\(Equipment\\)'
```